# Core Data - Object Properties Not Updating Correctly

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to keep track of a user's activities for any given day using Core Data; however I can't seem to work the object's relationships correctly. When I change a property of an "Activity" for a specific "Day", it's changed for all Days.  What am I missing? Thanks!

[image]

```
extension Day {

  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Day> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Day>(entityName: "Day")
  }

  @NSManaged public var date: String?
  @NSManaged public var seconds: Int32
  @NSManaged public var activities: Set<Activity>?

}

extension Activity {

  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Activity> {
      return NSFetchRequest<Activity>(entityName: "Activity")
  }

  @NSManaged public var name: String?
  @NSManaged public var time: Int32
  @NSManaged public var day: Set<Day>?

 }
```

Inside the Core Data manager class

```
func saveActivityForDay(day: String, activityName: String, activityTime: Int32) {
    // Get all Day objects from Core Data
    let currentArrDays = fetchAllDays()

    // Search for match for day
    if let index = currentArrDays.firstIndex(where: {$0.date == day}) {
        let dayToUpdate = currentArrDays[index]

        // Search for match for activity
        if let index = dayToUpdate.activities?.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == activityName}) {

            // If exists, update
            let activityToUpdate = dayToUpdate.activities?[index]
            activityToUpdate?.time = activityTime

        } else {

            // If it doesn't exist, create new
            let newActivity = Activity(context: self.context)

            newActivity.name = activityName
            newActivity.time = activityTime
            dayToUpdate.addToActivities(newActivity)
        }

        do {
            try self.context.save()
        } catch {
            print("issue saving existing day")
        }

    } else {
        // Day doesn't exist yet, create a new one
        saveNewDay(date: day, seconds: 0)
    }
}
```

Update:
[image]

Comment: You have a many-to-many relationship, is this really correct? A day can have many activities, that sound right but can the same activity really occur on several days?

Comment: Yes; my thinking was the user could have performed the same activity on separate days.

Comment: Ok but if you have an activity that is connected to 3 day objects and you change the `time` attribute for that activity this affects all 3 day objects and is the expected behavior with your current design. So what is your question then?

Comment: I see; thanks for pointing that out.  I want each day to have the same activities available, but with different properties on the activities.  Example: Day 1 has "Running "for "1 hour", and "Day 2" has Running for "2 hours".  If the user deletes "Running" as an Activity then it is deleted from all Days.  I changed the inverse relationship on the Activity to "To One" and updated above.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you pointed me in the right direction when you asked about the connection; I think my problem was partly a mistake there and partly an unrelated issue.  I know where to look a bit more now, thanks for the input!